# Error trying to upload an image from android to a server

Tags: android, http, web, server

I'm trying to make an application to take a photo and then uplad the photo to a server in java, but i can't get rid of this error

```
public void makeHTTPCall() {
    prgDialog.setMessage("Invoking JSP");
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Here is the error:

> "Class 'Anonymous class derived from asynchttpresponsehandler must
>   either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 
>   onFailure(int, Header[], byte[], Throwable) in
>   AsyncHttpResponseHandler"

```
    client.post("http://192.168.2.5:9999/ImageUploadWebApp/uploadimg.jsp", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
```

In these two following methods, it also says that they don't override from the super class

```
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    // Hide Progress Dialog
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                    // Hide Progress Dialog
                    prgDialog.hide();
                    // When Http response code is '404'
                    if (statusCode == 404) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code is '500'
                    else if (statusCode == 500) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Something went wrong at server end",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    // When Http response code other than 404, 500
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Error Occured \n Most Common Error: \n1. Device not connected to Internet\n2. Web App is not deployed in App server\n3. App server is not running\n HTTP Status code : "
                                        + statusCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Im following this tutorial, [Tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-upload-image-to-java-server/#server-app)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the below method to send multiple files with json request...

mImagePath is the arraylist of image paths

```
// Method for sending files using multiparting......
public static String sendJsonWithFile(Activity mActivity, ArrayList<String> mImagePaths, String jsonString, String URL)
{
    Log.e("json", jsonString);
    String res = "";
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.2.5:9999/ImageUploadWebApp/uploadimg.jsp");
        String boundary = "*****" + Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "*****";
        boundary = "--" + boundary;
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    StringBody stringBody = new StringBody(jsonString);

    reqEntity.addPart("formstring", stringBody);

    for (int i = 0; i < mImagePaths.size(); i++)
    {
        String imagePath = mImagePaths.get(i);
        if (mImagePaths != null && mImagePaths.size() > 0)
        {

            byte[] filebytes = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(imagePath));

            ByteArrayBody filebodyImage = new ByteArrayBody(filebytes, "image");
            Log.e("file path=", filebodyImage.toString());

            reqEntity.addPart("image", filebodyImage);

        }

    }

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    if (resEntity != null)
    {
        resEntity.consumeContent();
    }
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
{
    res = "UnsupportedEncodingException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (ClientProtocolException e)
{
    res = "ClientProtocolException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e)
{
    res = "FileNotFoundException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    res = "IOException";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    res = "Exception";
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return res;
```

}